# javascript serialize object while preserving the inheritance

Tags: javascript, serialization, browser-history, data-persistence

I have an object, say

```
O = {
    a1: instace_of_another_object,
    a2:100,
    a3:200
}
```

my a1 is inherited from another object say X.

How do I serialize and then deserialize O in such a way that I can call

```
O.a1.some_method() //which is part of X
```

If that is not possible, I am also Ok to store the object in localstorage proxy(which uses serialization). Is there a way I can "save" the whole object in "browser memory".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can do this with JSON.

You might want to look into using SOAP/REST.

You could also implement your own hydrator that takes certain properties from your JSON object and creates a new object using reflection (or simply setting values to properties)

Comment: I have to do it client side, also I did not exactly understand how to use hydrator for JSON

Comment: Basically a hydrator just takes JSON/REST/SOAP elements and sets them to the properties of an object.  Nothing too fancy :)  You would just have to implement custom rules.